# POCO HTTP Server: Request with Transfer-Encoding: chunked not complete

Tags: c++, http, poco-libraries

I have a HTTP server application written with the POCO libraries that needs to receive some chunked reqest data. My handler looks like this:

```cpp
void generic_post_method_handler(Poco::Net::HTTPServerRequest& request,
                                 Poco::Net::HTTPServerResponse& response)
{

    assert(request.getChunkedTransferEncoding());
    auto& stream = request.stream();
    std::string body;
    stream >> body;

    // do something with `body`

    response.send();
}
```

The server is configured with the default parameters: `m_srv(m_requestFactory, Poco::Net::ServerSocket(port), new Poco::Net::HTTPServerParams)`.

But I don't get the complete data in the body. Possibly it's just the first chunk that is returned.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.

The problem was not with `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` but with handling of streams.

I copied the received stream from the request into a `std::stringstream` and then I could convert it to a string:

```cpp
auto& stream = request.stream();
std::stringstream body;
Poco::StreamCopier::copyStream(stream, body);

const auto bodyString = body.str();
```